# Passing a parameter in the header (XML RPC)

Tags: php, parameters, curl, xml-rpc

I'm trying to set up a server status for the MMORPG Champions Online. I got some basic information from the web master and this is all he told me:

- XML-RPC call to server: http://www.champions-online.com/xmlrpc.php
- function name:  wgsLauncher.getServerStatus
- Parameter (language): en-US

Now, I found a nice example to start with [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2596), and I ended up with this code:

```
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

# Using the XML-RPC extension to format the XML package
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("wgsLauncher.getServerStatus", "<param><value><string>en-US</string></value></param>", null );

# Using the cURL extension to send it off, 
# first creating a custom header block
$header[] = "Host: http://www.champions-online.com:80/";
$header[] = "Content-type: text/xml";
$header[] = "Content-length: ".strlen($request) . "\r\n";
$header[] = $request;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.champions-online.com/xmlrpc.php"); # URL to post to
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); # return into a variable
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header ); # custom headers, see above
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST' ); # This POST is special, and uses its specified Content-type
$result = curl_exec( $ch ); # run!
curl_close($ch); 

echo $result;
?>
```

But I'm getting a "400 Bad Request" error. I'm new to XML RPC and I barely know php, so I'm at a loss. The [examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-encode-request.php) from the php site show how to use an array as a parameter, but nothing else.

I obtained the parameter string `<param><value><string>en-US</string></value></param>` from this [XMLRPC Debugger](http://gggeek.raprap.it/debugger/) (very nice btw). I entered the parameter I needed in the "payload" box and this was the output.

So, I would appreciate any help on how to pass this parameter to the header.

Note: My host supports [xmlrpc](http://phpinfo.byethost11.com/index.php) but it seems the function "xmlrpc_client" doesn't exist.

---

Update: The web master replied with this information, but it's still not working... it's getting to the point I may just scrape the status off the page.

```
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("wgsLauncher.getServerStatus", "en-US" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out my answer... It seemed to be a problem in the header, because it worked when I changed the cURL code to match the code I found it on [this site](http://www.nickycakes.com/post-to-wordpress-remotely-with-xmlrpc-in-php/). The post is about how to remotely post to wordpress using XMLRPC in php.

This is the code I ended up with:

```
<?php

// ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// error_reporting(E_ALL);

# Using the XML-RPC extension to format the XML package
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request( "wgsLauncher.getServerStatus", "en-US" );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.champions-online.com/xmlrpc.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$method = null;
$params = xmlrpc_decode_request($result, &$method); 

# server status result = true (up) or false (down)
$status = ($params['status']) ? 'up' : 'down';
$notice = ($params['notice'] == "") ? "" : "Notice: " + $params['notice'];
echo "Server Status: " . $status . "<br>";
echo $notice;

?>
```